# Puppeteer Promise Rejection (Query Selector If Class)

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, promise, puppeteer

I'm getting a promise rejection even if I use an if/else statement to check. When I iterate through divs (`const items`), the class `"description-main"` is on all of the items. However, the class `"description-optional"` isn't always present. How can I skip over it or assign `null` to it to continue through the loop without giving any errors?

```
// Imports: Dependencies
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

// Puppeteer: Generate CSV
(async () => {
    try {
       // Start Browser And Create New Page
       const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: false });
       const page = await browser.newPage();

       // Go To Page
       await page.goto('http://website.com', { waitUntil: 'networkidle2' });

       const items = await page.$$('.item');

       for (let i = 0; i <= items.length; i ++) {
          const itemDescription = await items[i].$eval('.description-main', div => div.innerText.trim());
          const itemDescription2 = null | await items[i].$eval('description-optional', div => div.innerText.trim());

          console.log('Item: ' + itemDescription + itemDescription2);
       }
   }
   catch (error) {
   console.log(error);
   }
 })()
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that `$eval` does multiple things which are dependent on each other.

`$eval` first selects the element and then attempts to evaluate the function on the result.

You can solve your problem in a few ways but the simplest is probably simply to check whether the selector matches an element before doing anything else:

`let itemDescription2;
if (await items[i].$('.description-optional')) 
    itemDescription2 = await items[i].$eval('description-optional', div => div.innerText.trim());`

Alternatively you could get the innerText within the browser and return it without causing an error.

Aso note:

`i <= items.length;` should be `i < items.length;`

and `description-optional` needs to be `.description-optional` as it is a class selector.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) to first verify that `await items[i].$('.description-optional')` is truthy (i.e. the element exists on the page).

If the condition is true (i.e. not [`null`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/null)), then you can execute and assign `await items[i].$eval('.description-optional', div => div.innerText.trim())` to `itemDescription2`.

Otherwise, assign [`null`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/null) to `itemDescription2`:

```
const itemDescription2 = await items[i].$('.description-optional') ? await items[i].$eval('.description-optional', div => div.innerText.trim()) : null;
```

Here is a full example:

```
const items = await page.$$('.item');

for (let i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
  const itemDescription = await items[i].$eval('.description-main', div => div.innerText.trim());
  const itemDescription2 = await items[i].$('.description-optional') ? await items[i].$eval('.description-optional', div => div.innerText.trim()) : null;

  console.log('Item: ' + itemDescription + itemDescription2);
}
```

Comment: instead of a ternary operator could be a short-circuit evaluation, since `.$()` return a null, something like this `const itemDescription2 = await items[i].$('.description-optional') && await items[i].$eval('.description-optional', div => div.innerText.trim())`